# Is it possible to build a chatroom strictly with html?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is the code that I have, using PHP and jquery. Here is my website http://bubblewschat.com . Part of the problem I'm having is the code shows up on the published website. How can I remove that and is it possible to build chatroom strictly with html?

```
<div id="page-wrap"> 
 <h2>Let's talk</h2> 
 <p id="name-area"></p> 
 <div id="chat-wrap"> 
  <div id="chat-area"></div> 
 </div> 
 <form id="send-message-area"> 
  <p>Your message: </p> 
  <textarea id="sendie" maxlength="100"></textarea> 
 </form>
</div>function Chat () { this.update = updateChat; this.send = sendChat; this.getState = getStateOfChat;}//gets the state of the chatfunction getStateOfChat() { if(!instanse){ instanse = true; $.ajax({ type: &quot;POST&quot;, url: &quot;process.php&quot;, data: {'function': 'getState', 'file': file}, dataType: &quot;json&quot;, success: function(data) {state = data.state;instanse = false;} }); } }//Updates the chatfunction updateChat() { if(!instanse){ instanse = true; $.ajax({ type: &quot;POST&quot;, url: &quot;process.php&quot;, data: {'function': 'update','state': state,'file': file}, dataType: &quot;json&quot;, success: function(data) { if(data.text){ for (var i = 0; i &lt; data.text.length; i++) { $('#chat-area').append($(&quot; &quot;+ data.text[i] +&quot; &quot;)); } } document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight; instanse = false; state = data.state; } }); } else { setTimeout(updateChat, 1500); }}//send the messagefunction sendChat(message, nickname) { updateChat(); $.ajax({ type: &quot;POST&quot;, url: &quot;process.php&quot;, data: {'function': 'send','message': message,'nickname': nickname,'file': file}, dataType: &quot;json&quot;, success: function(data){ updateChat(); } });}
<!--?php    $function = $_POST['function'];        $log = array();        switch($function) {           case('getState'):           if (file_exists('chat.txt')) {               $lines = file('chat.txt');           }           $log['state'] = count($lines);            break;               case('update'):          $state = $_POST['state'];          if (file_exists('chat.txt')) {             $lines = file('chat.txt');          }          $count =  count($lines);          if ($state == $count){             $log['state'] = $state;             $log['text'] = false;          } else {             $text= array();             $log['state'] = $state + count($lines) - $state;             foreach ($lines as $line_num =--> $line) { if ($line_num &gt;= $state){ $text[] = $line = str_replace(&quot;\n&quot;, &quot;&quot;, $line); } } $log['text'] = $text; } break; case('send'): $nickname = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['nickname'])); $reg_exUrl = &quot;/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/&quot;; $message = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message'])); if (($message) != &quot;\n&quot;) { if (preg_match($reg_exUrl, $message, $url)) { $message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '
<a href="'.$url[0].'" target="_blank">'.$url[0].'</a>', $message); } fwrite(fopen('chat.txt', 'a'), &quot;
<span>&quot;. $nickname . &quot;</span>&quot; . $message = str_replace(&quot;\n&quot;, &quot; &quot;, $message) . &quot;\n&quot;); } break; } echo json_encode($log);?&gt;
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="chat.js"></script>
<script>  // ask user for name with popup prompt      var name = prompt("Enter your chat name:", "Guest");   // default name is 'Guest'  if (!name || name === ' ') {    name = "Guest";    }    // strip tags  name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");    // display name on page  $("#name-area").html("You are: <span>" + name + "</span>");    // kick off chat  var chat =  new Chat();  $(function() {       chat.getState();           // watch textarea for key presses     $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {                var key = event.which;              //all keys including return.           if (key >= 33) {                        var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");               var length = this.value.length;                            // don't allow new content if length is maxed out             if (length >= maxLength) {                   event.preventDefault();               }           }                                                                                                       });     // watch textarea for release of key press     $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {                          if (e.keyCode == 13) {                       var text = $(this).val();              var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");                var length = text.length;                              // send               if (length <= maxLength + 1) {                 chat.send(text, name);                  $(this).val("");              } else {                $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));              }          }     });  });</script>
```

Comment: Could you please format your code properly ? We simply can't read / understand it at the moment.

Comment: Your code has many issues. One of those is that you forgot the `<script type="text/javascript">` after the last `</div>`. Suggesting to clean it and post a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) link.

Answer (score 1):

`Is it possible to build a chatroom strictly with html?`

No.

A chatroom is an interactive site that takes input from multiple users and displays it to multiple users. it therefore needs some code that will be able to do that.

html is not a programming language. It is a markup Language - ie it has code that you can use to tell a browser that "this piece of text is a paragraph"... but that's about the extent of it.

To write a chatroom, you will need to use something like PHP/javascript/ruby etc... which means it has to be run by a server/browser that actually *runs* the PHP...

Answer (score -1):

$url[0]You have to wrap your `$variables` declaration in php tags like this
`<?php` declaration `?>`

That will tell your server to interpret the code as Php. Concerning your question you can build a chat room with Html AND Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML).

Since php is rendered server side, you will need Ajax to make the calls for posting messages, polling for received messages and display of the messages.

Comment: `function chat() ...` seems to be some Javascript code btw, not PHP.